# Independence of function extensionality

Tags: type-theory, history, functional-extensionality

Who first realized that function extensionality cannot be proved within vanilla MLTT, or some variations of it? Now to my knowledge the simplest way to show this is by [syntactic models](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01445835/document). But surely there are much earlier proofs.

Comment: The simple syntactic model doesn't have Pi eta. The simplest countermodel with full Pi types is the [polynomial model](https://github.com/AndrasKovacs/polynomial-model).

Comment: The parametric exceptional syntactic model has both eta for $\Pi$ and negates funext, and IMO it's simpler than the polynomial model (which is itself a variant of Dialectica) because you don't have to rely on a sufficiently extensional metatheory. More generally, "realizability"-like models that do not bake in a setoid model will also break funext. It was observed very early that funext was not true in many realizability models for weaker logics, but I don't have a reference.

Comment: I don't know if it's the earliest, but Streicher's [Investigations into Intensional Type Theory](https://www2.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~streicher/HabilStreicher.pdf) contains quite a few such results for realizability-like models.